# Share monk AC bonus with animal companion mount?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, animal-companions, mount, armor-class

I have a [swift and deadly hunter variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#druid) druid, who gains “Bonus to Armor Class when unarmored (as monk, including Wisdom bonus to AC).”

He rides his animal companion as a mount. I was wondering if there was any feat, or other option, that would allow him to share that AC bonus with his mount. The only option for this that I can find is the [sohei monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/sohei/), but that requires four levels in an otherwise-useless-to-me class, and also does a lot more than I require. A feat would be ideal, but a dip of fewer and/or better levels (ideally both), a spell (ideally a low-level, long-lasting druid one), magic item (ideally cheap), or whatever else will be considered. The benefit must not require actions in combat, however, and cannot be limited in the number of hits it will cover in a given round (because Mounted Combat would be far better in that case).

Official D&D 3.5e products, licensed D&D 3.5e products, official Pathfinder products, and Dreamscarred Press 3.5e or Pathfinder products are preferred, but third-party 3.5e products and other third-party Pathfinder products will be considered.

Options for allowing his mount to add her own Wisdom modifier to AC would not be particularly helpful; her Wisdom is 10 less than his. So no just buying her a *monk’s belt* and being done with it.

Comment: Roger and thank you for the pointer (where the top answer explicitly points out "leads on" answers). I won't move it to a full answer as you explicitly mentioned a better approach in the question.

Comment: @Bainos Combining your suggestion with [your answer to my other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125239/4563) would make for a fairly-decent answer—I probably don’t want 6 levels of vigilante any more than I want 4 levels of monk, but vigilante *is* a better class in general, and I can imagine cases where it would be a superior choice to sohei.

Comment: Sohei's ability (and the UnMonk's *Ki Mount* power) would probably use the mount's wisdom, as [clarified (vaguely) by Mark Seifter (Developer)](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r7kg&page=84?Ask-Mark-Seifter-All-Your-Questions-Here#4178).

Comment: @ShadowKras ...right, well. [I recognize that the developers have made a ruling, but given that it’s a stupid-ass ruling, I’ve elected to ignore it.](https://78.media.tumblr.com/d96d104bfcfc573997b31c56056ff467/tumblr_n3q2w6mfQk1rcwa0zo6_250.gif) It’s correct as-written, but it’s also completely terrible.

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically want to share AC instead of just making the mount independently great?

Comment: @fectin When I ask questions, I almost-always ask very specific questions. I already *have* a question on how to make the mount great. In this case, I was simply surprised that nothing like this existed, and wondered if anyone else could find it where I couldn’t.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Feats or abilities that would facilitate what you are asking for (other than sohei monk's ability), if you simply wanted AC for your mount John's answer would be your best bet however obviously this isn't what you want so no unless you use sohei monk/vigilante, you can't share your unarmoured defense with your mount.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, and thanks for taking the time to help me out here. I think you very well may be right, but it is important that answers here are backed up—proving a negative is impossible, but it would improve your answer if you described how you are sure and what sources you have ruled out.