# Do any archetypes for non-monk classes get ki powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype

Quite simply, are there any archetypes for non-monk classes that gain *ki* powers as a monk does? That is, gets powers that are found on the *ki* power list of the monk (any archetype).

Any official Paizo material, any Dreamscarred Press material (though I’m about 98% sure none helps), or any third-party Pathfinder material I can access online through an SRD is acceptable.

I am absolutely uninterested in any monk archetypes, or in any non-monk archetypes that get something “kind of like” *ki* powers. They have to be actual *ki* powers on an actual non-monk class. Answers with archetypes that get some specified *ki* power are OK as an answer, but ultimately I am hoping for something that will let me pick my choice of *ki* power.

Comment: The form of this question is fairly broad, but I’ve already done some digging and I believe the answer to be *no*, so I expect that any positive answers will have a fairly-limited collection of options.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *ki power*? Any ability that uses *ki*? Specifically a power off the Unchained Monk's list of *ki* powers? Something off the Qinggong Monk's list of *ki* powers? It's a little unclear what you want.

Comment: @Delioth Anything off of the *ki* power list of any monk archetype, say. So not ninja tricks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any other archetypes, but there are a couple of Prestige Classes that can learn Ki Powers.

The [Student of Perfection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/student-of-perfection/) is one. Of course, the entry requirements for the class are Improved Unarmed Strike, and [Perfect Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-style-combat-style/), which itself requires BAB +5 or 5 levels in Monk, and the Ki Power doesn't kick in until level 2 of the Prestige Class, meaning at least level 7 before getting a Ki Power, and the easiest way to qualify is to already be a monk, but those aren't absolutely required.

There's also the [Psychic Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-prestige-classes/psychic-fist/), which needs 6 ranks in Acrobatics, leading to the first Ki Power at level 2 of the class (minimum character level 8).

There's also the [Unchained Ninja](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/alternate-classes/everyman-gaming-unchained-ninja/), from Everyman Games, which can take a Master Trick at level 10, one of which is to take any Ki Power.

Comment: Student of perfection might work for me, thank you.

Comment: @Kryan No worries - I am glad the non-archetype options might help out!

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Teisatsu](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Vigilante%20Teisatsu) Vigilante archetype. This archetype gets the following vigilante talent:

> **Ki Power** (Su): The teisatsu gains a single ki power of his choice from the list available to the unchained monk class.